# Add class to the last <li> in a group of <ul>

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a group of `<ul>`'s created dynamically and i need a class added to the last `<li>` of each one.

I have:

```
$('ul li:last').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("last");
});
```

But this only adds a `class="last"` to the last `<ul>` not in all of the `<ul>`'s.

I want the last `<li>` of each `<ul>` to get added the class, not just the last `<ul>`.

Comment: FYI, html tags are rendered literally on StackOverflow. If you want to include html snippets in your code, surround them with backticks (in general that's how you include code snippets in your text, as opposed to the indented code blocks). I edited your answer to fix the formatting. Please take a look at what I did so you can do this for your questions in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), a propriety jQuery selector, pops off the last element from the set and returns it.

[`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), the CSS selector, selects the last child of each ancestor element.

```
$('ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaNMk/).

As a side note, you don't need to use `each()` there. The `addClass()` will be ran over each item in the jQuery set.