# how to add or append a class to the last li element using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel

I currently don't understand why is the last children of li element is not inserting to the last li, this module is treeview. the only main goal that i need to achieve is to add class to last li.
so to understand well I will show you the sample code and illustration on the below.

As you can see, the added class is on other li but suppose to be the added class of ('last') is on the check mark.

**Problem:** the added class of ('last') is not on the right last li.

**I have two html page.**

1. posting.blade.php
2. manage_child.blade.php

[image: sample image]

**posting.blade.php:**

```
   <ul id="tree1">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <li>
                {{ $category->title }}
                @if(count($category->childs))
                    @include('/SuperAdmin/manage_child',['childs' => $category->childs])
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

**manage_child.blade.php:**

```
    <ul>
@foreach($childs as $child)
    <li>
        {{ $child->title }}
    @if(count($child->childs))
            @include('/SuperAdmin/manage_child',['childs' => $child->childs])
        @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

**Treeview Js:**

```
    $.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {

        var openedClass = 'far fa-minus-square';
        var closedClass = 'far fa-plus-square';

      if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
        }
        if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
        }
      };

        //initialize each of the top levels

        var tree = $(this);

        tree.addClass("tree");



        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {



            var branch = $(this); //li with children ul

            branch.prepend("<i class=' " + closedClass + "'></i>");

            branch.addClass('branch');

            tree.find('li').not('li.branch').css( "background", "yellow" );

            branch.on('click', function (e) {

                if (this == e.target) {


                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');

                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);


                    $(this).children().children().toggle();

                    if (branch.find('li').last()) {
                        branch.find('li').last().addClass('last');
                    }
                }


            })

            branch.children().children().toggle();

        });

        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
        tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();


            });
        });

        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();
```

**CSS:**

```
    #tree1, #tree1 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none
}
#tree1 ul {
    margin-left:1em;
    position:relative
}
#tree1 ul ul {
    margin-left:.5em
}
#tree1 ul:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-left:1px solid
}
#tree1 li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 1em;
    line-height:2em;
    font-weight:700;
    position:relative
}
#tree1 ul li:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:0;
    border-top:1px solid;
    margin-top:-1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1em;
    left:0
}
#tree1 ul li:last-child:before {
    background:#fff;
    height:auto;
    top:1em;
    bottom:0
}
.indicator {
    margin-right:5px;
}
#tree1 li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#369;
}
#tree1 li button, #tree1 li button:active, #tree1 li button:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#369;
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Also I want to remove the yellow background of the class .branch children

[image: problem]

Comment: This thread may useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185361/add-class-to-the-last-li-in-a-group-of-ul

Comment: that appears to be exactly what he used, which won't work because it just finds the first level's last match

Comment: yes aruna. i know it helps, I already find that thread. The solution answered to that thread is not working on my side. as you can see on the illustration. the added class in not on the right li

Comment: @user120242 yah your correct.

Comment: did you try `x=branch.find('li').last()`, or this, or whatever context it's supposed to be in

Comment: what does x variable ?

Comment: nothing, it's just there.  all that does is collect all the li, and take the last one it finds.  jQuery searches in order, so it should work

Comment: where should i put this x=branch.find('li').last()

Comment: are you referring to this ?  if (branch.find('li').last()) {
                        branch.addClass('last'); 
                    }

Comment: if yes, the added class is still on the first level

Comment: so instead of branch.is, which adds the class to current element, you just do branch.find('li').last().addClass('last');  just to make sure I'm understanding you though, you want to traverse the entire tree and find the last node by order of when they are occurring in the html right?

Comment: yah. thanks who you are user120242 , it works now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to traverse down the tree and get the last one.  This collects all the `li` and takes the last one, then adds the last class.  Use this in place of your .is statement.

```
branch.find('li').last().addClass('last');
```

Just to be sure, if you want it from the current clicked element you will want to use this:

```
$(this).find('li').last().addClass('last');
```

Comment: hi can i ask something. how to add class in all li but not in the branch? tree.find('li').not('li.branch').css( "background", "yellow" ); if i used this also the branch class has yellow background

Comment: I would just ask, are you sure you want to do that?  if it's for styles maybe just use `#tree1.tree li:not(.branch) { background-color: yellow }`

Comment: the problem here is. i just want to background-color yellow all li tags. but not on the branch class and also not in li branch children.

Comment: because right now. after i used this tree.find('li').not('li.branch').css( "background", "yellow" ); the .branch class is not highlighting anymore. but inside of .branch children has a yellow background. if you want to see on it. i will edit my post.

Comment: right, you need $('tree > li:not(.branch) li').css('background','yellow')